# AS3 Compiler Asserts / Force Compiler Exception

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, assertions

We've got a project that has the all source in one git repository, but then a collection of used libraries in another 'frameworks' repository.  We've now got decent enough automatic versioning happening with git tags, but what we'd really like to do is to throw a big obvious "project version doesn't match frameworks one", when "0.00.001" is the version tagged for the client repo, but "0.00.002" is the version tagged for the project repo.

This could be as simple a check as

```
assert(a != b)
```

But after a decent amount of googling and research, I can't actually see how to do that in actionscript, or with the AS3 / Flex / AIR sdks, I thought it was possible, but can't see how.

Thanks for any help given.

Comment: The version number is only in a git tag? The Flex/Flash compilers don't know about git or how to read version info from it. I'm not aware of any way to throw or force a compile time error (other than having typos in your code). One approach would be to have your build system pass in [compiler variables](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_21.html) at compile time, and throwing the error if they don't match at runtime.

Comment: Sorry SunilD., I've already got a file being automatically created through an ant task to populate a template file with the git tags, so that part's not a problem.  I'm asking specifically about AS3 Compiler asserts and how to do them, if possible.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to create your own compile-time errors in ActionScript.